# Bundle gem load error in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

Attempting to install a [theme](https://mmistakes.github.io/minimal-mistakes/docs/installation/) for Jekyll while learning Jekyll/Ruby from scratch, I messed up something. Now I get an error message whenever I execute `bundle`. Anyone know how to fix?

```
$ bundle -v
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- 
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

There are many mentions to the error in the web, but also a general lack of consistency in answers/suggestions.

I went ahead and

1. `apt-get --purge autoremove ruby`
2. erased `/var/lib/gems/`
3. `apt-get install ruby`
4. `apt-get install ruby-dev`
5. `gem install jekyll`

but problem persists.

Is the issue perhaps akin to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308070/gem-bundler-load-error-cant-activate-already-activated), with similar solution?

Some relevant info:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
$ gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
...
bundler (default: 1.16.1)
...
```

Running ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this `$ gem update --system  2.7.4`

Comment: Thanks @kalpeshdav, this seems to have done the trick! Could you pls elaborate on what the issue is about?

Comment: More info: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/2180#issuecomment-366763329

Answer (score 8):

In my case mixed installed versions were the root cause. Reinstalling bundler helped.

1. Deinstall all versions:

```
gem uninstall bundler
```

2. Reinstall the latest version:

```
gem install bundler
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a Gemfile.lock that was bundled with that specific version requires this version. I opened that Gemfile.lock and set BUNDLED WITH version to my updated bundler and was good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Kalpeshdav's answer, specifying the version number, seems to work in a lot of cases and is recommended in various places around github etc.

However I've run into a couple of times where it didn't work. My situation was basically that I was running different jekyll sites in different directories as well as other static site applications like Hugo and https://github.com/slatedocs/slate which are also based in Ruby and Bundle/Bundler.

In a recent situation I was receiving this error message both when I ran 'bundle exec jekyll serve' and 'bundle install'. I tried removing and reinstalling bundler and updating gem, neither worked for me. And then I realized that somehow my local Gemfile.lock file was determining how my bundle commands were running. So I moved the Gemfile.lock into a backup location outside of the directly and reran bundle install. That worked and I was subsequently able to run 'bundle exec jekyll serve'.